# The smoothness of an inclusion map

Tags: manifolds

Let $M$ and $N$ be manifolds and let $q_0$ be a point in $N$. Prove that the inclusion map $i_{q_0} : M \to M×N : p \mapsto (p,q_0)$, is $C^\infty$.

Comment: What is C¥? Is it $C^{\infty}$?

Comment: Let M and N be manifolds and let q0 be a point in N. Prove that the inclusion map iq0 : M →
M×N, iq0 (p) = (p,q0), is c^∞.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds, try this:

Let $p\in U\subset M$ and let $(\phi,U)$ be a chart on $M$. Also, let $(p,q_0)\in U\times W\subset M\times N$ and let $(\psi,U\times W)$ be a chart on $M\times N$. Then the problem reduces to smoothness of the induced map $\tilde{i_{q_0}}:\phi(U)\rightarrow \psi|_{U\times \{q_0\}}(U)$ where $x\mapsto (x,y_0)$ for a fixed $y_0$, which we know is smooth.

Comment: whay Let p∈U⊂M  and let (ϕ,U)  be a chart on M . Also, let (p,q 0 )∈U×W⊂M×N  and let (ψ,U×W)  be a chart on M×N . Then the problem reduces to smoothness of the induced map i q 0   ~ :ϕ(U)→ψ| U×{q 0 } (U)  where x↦(x,y 0 )  for a fixed y 0  , which we know is smooth.

Comment: @hamid Are you a bot or a real person?